# How to ensure correct/direct dimension scaling on android in layouts and elsewhere?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

Is there any unit that I can use that would scale directly? Is the only way really to write everything in px and multiply it by correct scale ?

(`scale = <real screen height>/<template base height> . and every dimension is <dimen in px> * scale`)

"dp" with the bucket approach does not work for me - I'm writing for small screens where the element is long off the screen before the next dp scaling threshold is triggered.

Currently my workaround for drawing on canvas is (below) but I dont know how to reconcile it with using xml layouts

```
@Override
    public void onSurfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
        super.onSurfaceChanged(holder, format, width, height);
        screenScale = ((float) width) / (float) mBackgroundBitmap.getWidth();
        mTopBarYOffset = mTopBarYOffset * screenScale;
        mTopBarXOffset = mTopBarXOffset * screenScale;
//and so on for every dimension
```

Comment: I'm trying to align layout elements to borders pre drawn on the background so I need it to look exacly the same on every screen not roughly the same - 3px of difference throws whole layout off. Some unit like %(of screen) wold be ideal but it does not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout).

In `ConstraintLayout` you can work with percent like this:

```
 <Button
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.6" //line 1
    app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.5"  //line 2 
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    />
```

**So what I did -** I told my button to be equal to 60% of its parent in height (see line 1) 
and also I told my button to be equal to 50% of its parent Width(see line 2).

For more complex layouts I would also use [guidelines](https://constraintlayout.com/basics/guidelines.html) and [Chains](https://constraintlayout) to make it easier to make a responsive layout.

Comment: Thanks that work pretty well! Little off topic ... is there any way to make editor use/calculate `_percent` instead of `layout_width/height` when I move/resize elements? Wold be nice to drag&drop instead of typing from time to time.

Comment: I don't think so, I think that you are making your view's size in dp when you stretch them from the editor. If this was helpful please accept the answer so it can help another developers with the same problem.

Comment: i jumped the gun with  "it works".  It works for element width and height but what about margins? After some fiddling I Don't see any way to make a margin left for ex. = 0.132 of parent. So half of solution - I can create elements but I don't have a way to position them on screen

Comment: small margin sizes like `8dp` or `16dp` are fine, I have an app in google play store with fixed-sized margins and because they are small it looks good on all devices.

Comment: I can do it by using guidelines for each margin but it seems more like a workaround than a solution... Also it's for wear os so screen size about 3cm in height. When using dp difference in position bay be 4-5mm depending on screen -unnoticeable on phone but half of the text off screen on the watch

Comment: Are you using very large margins sizes like `100dp`? .If not you don't need to worry about it.

Comment: i did it using relative layout and dp but after trying it on smaller smartwatch  the config layout that was ok on my watch was thrown all over the place on the smaller one.

Comment: I was talking only about phones layouts, I think that if you want to develop a layout for wearables you can use another layout type as mentioned in  [wearables](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/ui/layouts) documentation.

Comment: I know about the wearable layouts but they all have the same issue - too big jumps between dp scalling. They still work the same way that if I declare margin of  16dp on one screen it will align fine with background with 5x5 grid but on other one the text in last row will start in the middle of the grid. If I align elements to screen I need to use large values, if I align to previous elements the" rounding errors" accumulate end effect is the same So so long as this is not changed for wear os by google Constaint layout is the only way to go.